# Classification of symplectic representations of quaternion division algebras

Tags: rt.representation-theory, abstract-algebra, quaternions

I would like to know the classification of representations of the form $\rho:B^{\times}\to Sp(V,F)$ or ($Gsp(V)$), where $B$ is a quaternion division algebra over a number field $F$ (or $F=\mathbb{Q}$) ($B^{\times}$ is the multiplicative group). In other words all of isomorphism classes of such irreducible representations. I would appreciate any reference to this.

Comment: What do you mean when you write $B\to Sp(V)$ ? What kind of morphism is that supposed to be? On the left hand side there is an algebra, on the right hand side, there is a group. Do you mean the additive group of $B$ ? That has nothing to do with division algebras, that's just the additive group of a vector space. Do you mean the multiplicative group of $B$ ?

Comment: Sorry I edited my question. The quaternion algebra is cosidered over a number field (and therefore it is not anymore isomorphic to Hamiltonians)

Comment: What kind of a homomorphism is $\rho$? Is it just a homomorphism between two discrete groups?

Comment: Actually the really interesting case for me is when the homoomrphism is an algebraic groups homomrphism. But for the beginning one can treat them as discrete groups.

Comment: If you're wanting an algebraic group morphism, the discrete-group scenario is pretty irrelevant, I think. Rather, perhaps asking for _topological_ repns first, if anything. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: @paul garrett: you are right. I would appreciate any information, topological representations are of course more relevant.